# What is Polymorphism?

Tags: c#, .net, oop, polymorphism

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Try to describe polymorphism as easy as you can](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/210460/try-to-describe-polymorphism-as-easy-as-you-can)

What is polymorphism?

Comment: see also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/234458/does-polymorphism-or-conditionals-promote-better-design http://stackoverflow.com/questions/933831/implementing-polymorphism-in-c-how-best-to-do-it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2530893/is-this-an-example-of-polymorphism http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2400284/is-method-overloading-considered-part-of-polymorphism http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2423231/polymorphism-relates-inheritance http://stackoverflow.com/questions/367276/what-is-the-difference-between-abstraction-and-polymorphism

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please read [MSDN which covers it in reference to c#](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173152%28VS.80%29.aspx),

Basically a derived class inherits from another class it gets all its methods,events and properties, and every type is polymorphic in .NET since they all have Object as their base class.